# what is ambiguity in alphabet in automata theory?

Tags: tokenize, automata-theory

I am just new in automata field. I have read many articles, and seen many video. I stuck in some first topics. It can be easy for others. but after spending a lot of time,i am still unable to understand it. 
TOPIC is: Ambiguity in alphabet

An alphabet is = {A, Aa, bab, d}
and a string is s= AababA

and author says that, this is ambiguous alphabet, because when computer reads it , it reads from left to right. After the capital A, there again A that is prefix of small a, will create ambiguity. A letter(symbol) should not be prefix again of a new letter. 
moreover author says. 
we will tokenize it (AababA) in two ways:

- (Aa) (bab) (A)
- (A) (abab) (A)

after that , first one is ok, second is not ok due to ambiguity in alphabet define above.

1. What is procedure to tokenize the above string in two ways? is there any specific rule?
2. How alphabet is ambiguous due to second group.
3. If it is invalid due to prefix of A, then how? What is the role of prefix in ambiguity of alphabet?
4. If we don't think about prefix, and we just simply match the both string group with above alphabet, then we can easily judge, that second is not matching with above alphabet, then why do we need to discuss that prefix?

I hope, this question will be considered important, so that answer will help me to make my self out of this confusion. I will be very thankful .

Comment: I think that your tokenization is flawed - `(Aa)(bab)(d)` is flowed because there's no (d) symbol in the end of string and `(A)(Abab)(A)` is flowed because there's no (Abab) symbol in alphabet. String should be tokenized as `(Aa)(bab)(A)`. Also no ambiguity here - tokenization in form of (A)... fails, because there's no valid next match according to alphabet.

Comment: Please see it now.

Answer (score 0):

The author chose a confusing example. If you share the source where you got this example, I could give a better answer, but I would argue that in this case, there is no **practical** ambiguity. If you see `Aa`, you can know that the first lexeme must be "Aa", because nothing in the alphabet starts with "a".

For an easier example, consider the alphabet {A, a, Aa} and string "AAaAaaA"

You could tokenize this in the following ways:

```
(A) (A) (a) (A) (a) (a) (A)
(A) (Aa) (A) (a) (a) (A)
(A) (A) (a) (Aa) (a) (A)
(A) (Aa) (Aa) (A)
```

This is most often resolved by choosing the longest lexeme that matches in each case, which would yield the last tokenization.

---

Now let us return to your example, but let's make the string a little bit different: "AababAe".

You could tokenize the string in the following ways:

```
(Aa) (bab) (A) <error>
(A) <error>
```

In one branch, you have an error. In one branch, you don't. As you noted, the tokenizer should choose the first. Both have errors, though. The point is that there is an explicit choice here to prefer the longest valid tokenization. Nothing in the alphabet forces you to make this choice. It is just as valid to choose the shortest matching option. This would be massively impractical, but it is a valid choice.